# Can't create a function in PowerShell

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

I'm trying to add a menu-item in my PowerShell ISE by using [this tutorial](http://www.powershellatoms.com/shell-environment/adding-functions-to-the-powershell-ise-menu/).

```
Function My-Custom-Function { 
    Write-Host “Running my very own function!” 
}

$psISE.CustomMenu.Submenus.Add(“Run Custom Function”, {My-Custom-Function}, “Shift+Ctrl+f”)
```

But for some reason I get this error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:5 char:31
+ $psISE.CustomMenu.Submenus.Add <<<< (“Run Custom Function”, {My-Custom-Function}, “Shift+Ctrl+f”)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Add:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I run Windows 7 Enterprise and I run the PowerShell ISE as Administrator...

Any thoughts about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Function My-Custom-Function { 
    Write-Host “Running my very own function!” 
}

$psISE.CurrentPowerSHellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add(“Run Custom Function”, {My-Custom-Function}, "Shift+Ctrl+f")

This works for V3 on my system!!

Answer (score 0):

The text:

$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add(“Run Custom Function”, {My-Custom-Function}, "Shift+Ctrl+f")

could better be changed to

$psISE.PowerShellTabs.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add(“Run Custom Function”, {My-Custom-Function}, "Shift+Ctrl+f")

Assuming you want the add-on menu for all PowerShell tabsl